# Adding new table to sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

For SQLiteOpenHelper, if I add a new table inside `onCreate` do I have to do anything inside `onUpgrade`? I am adding a completely new table. I believe I have to change the version number but that `onUpgrade` should remain empty. Is that correct?

Comment: Have you already released a previous version of your app?

Comment: Yes, I have :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want existing installs of the app to add this new table, then yes, you must increase the version and provide a suitable `onUpgrade()` implementation, as well as adding the table in `onCreate()` (which you stated you have already done).

An empty `onUpgrade()` implementation is not sufficient; it has to actually do something. Some people drop all tables and just call `onCreate()` directly, but this obviously doesn't work well if you are trying to keep existing data. I usually use the fall-through `switch` idiom, so that if a user is more than one version behind (e.g. you publish a version 3 and a user is still on version 1) they will go through all the necessary upgrades sequentially:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    switch (oldVersion) {
        case 1:
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + ...);
            // no break statement, so case 2 will execute after this.
        case 2:
            // more execSQL(), etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you're only developing (so nobody else has the app yet), you could skip the upgrade and just do `onCreate()` only, but you'll have to remove the database so it gets recreated. You can do this by uninstalling and reinstalling, or finding the app in Settings > Apps and clearing its data there.

Answer (score 1):

`onCreate()` will not be called if a user already has installed your app previously. So you need to create the new table in `onUpgrade()`, too. Be sure to increase the version number of your database.

I suggest putting the code to create the table in a helper method so that you can call it from both callback methods. This will reduce the chance of an error in case you need to change the code to create the table.

Answer (score 0):

onUpgrade will only be called if you increase the version number.

To implement it you must recreate the tables with any changes you have made and copy over any existing data. There are many tutorials on this topic.

It is not necessary to implement if you are still learning, but if you don't and you make any changes to your schema you'll need to uninstall the app from the device or the changes won't be applied.